# VueJS - Best way to open global modal login form

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My VueJs project uses Axios to send server requests.
Some of server-side requests needs authenticated user with JWT.

I would like to make a generic client-side service to make these authenticated requests and, if not authenticated, my user needs to be shown a modal login form.

So, I created a Mixin to do so:

```
import ModalLogin from '../../components/ModalLogin';
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
    components: {
        ModalLogin
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            ModalLoginComponent
        }
    },
    methods: { 
        authorizedGet(url) {
            if(!localStorage.getItem('user')) {
                this.instantiateModal()
                this.data().ModalLoginComponent.methods.show()
            }
        },
        instantiateModal() {
            var ModalLoginClass = Vue.extend(ModalLogin)
            this.ModalLoginComponent = new ModalLoginClass()
            this.ModalLoginComponent.$mount()
        }
    }
}
```

and a basic ModalLogin component.
But, obviously, I don't know how to add my ModalLogin to my DOM from a mixin.
I'd like my modal to be global for all my app.

Comment: For a setup that doesn't involve modal manager there's only one way, you need to use modal component once (the way components are used in Vue, i.e. in the template) somewhere at high level like app component, and call `show()` on its ref. The rest is of the task is to interact with app component, and there are many ways to do that - Vuex, etc

Comment: Why in a Mixin? Are you gonna re-use that same logic other than your Dialog component?